# three.js boundingBox around OBJMTLLoader object for mouse-picking

Tags: javascript, three.js, bounding-box

I´m searching for an solution to get a bounding box around an object I have loaded with the OBJMTLLoader. I need this because my loaded Object doesn't react on my mouse picking methods so I will try to make it run with a boundingBox.

This what I tried at last:

```
function furnitureII(){
var loaderI = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loaderI.load('models/lettoCiliegio.obj', 'models/lettoCiliegio.mtl', function(object) {
    var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object);    
    object.position.z = 5;
    object.position.y = -5.95;
    object.position.x = 10;
    object.scale.set(0.05,0.05,0.05);
    scene.add(bbox);
});    
}
```

Error: TypeError: bbox.position is undefined
If i set a position for the box it also doesn´t work.

```
function furnitureII(){
var loaderI = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loaderI.load('models/lettoCiliegio.obj', 'models/lettoCiliegio.mtl', function(object) {
    var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object); 
    bbox.position.set(2,-4,0);
    object.position.z = 5;
    object.position.y = -5.95;
    object.position.x = 10;
    object.scale.set(0.05,0.05,0.05);
    scene.add(bbox);
});}
```

Comment: please explain what the problem is with the current code (and show error messages, if any)

Comment: when i click the button the 3d object won´t added to the scene.  ERROR: TypeError: bbox.position is undefined. When i set a position for the box it neither works.

Comment: when you set a position for the box, do you get the same error? if not, please also provide the new error, and please update your question with the added info, as it is essential.

Comment: `Box3()` is not an `Object3D`. It does not have a `position`. Usually the bbox follows the object so you shouldn't need to set its position.